# How do I export a higher resolution image of a Mathematica Graph object?

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

How do I export a re-sized version of the output I get from a call to `GraphPlot` 
(or `TreePlot` if they produce different output) to a jpg file?
Currently, I'm simply calling `Export[file_name, G]`
where `G` is the result from a call to something like `GraphPlot`. 
I'm using Microsoft office picture manager to view the jpgs, 
but re-scaling them there yields unsatisfactory results due to poor resolution 
(the graph I'm trying to plot has strings as labels which can't be made out after rescaling this way). I would like to be able to choose the size/resolution of the rendered jpg.

Comment: Do you have to use a jpg file? It might be better to use a [vector based image](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/VectorGraphicsFormats.html) instead of a [rasterized](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/RasterImageFormats.html) one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Simon already pointed out, don't use a raster-format for a vector-graphics. Instead, export you plot to e.g. a scalable vector graphics:

```
graph = GraphPlot[ExampleData[{"Matrix", "HB/can_292"}, "Matrix"]];
Export["graph.svg", graph]
```

The advantage is, that in such an image, you can still adjust and change lines, polygons and colors. And finally, you can export it to an image of arbitrary quality easily.

[image]

And remember, for Plots which contain lines, polygons, ... everything with sharp edges you should never use jpg. General speaking, this is a format for photographs only since its compression is made for reducing filesize in *natural* images. In those images you don't recognize the compression, in images with text, lines and polygons you certainly will notice the artefacts. Use png if possible. Take your browser and zoom into the above image.

Comment: also consider EPS, PDF and (on Windows) EMF, depending on your requirement.

Comment: Yes, all the other vector formats are as good as svg. I mentioned svg explicitely because with Inkscape (http://inkscape.org/) you have an open source drawing program.

Comment: Strictly speaking, in general EMF is worse than PDF and EPS because it samples vector graphics at screen resolution fidelity and because it cannot embed fonts.

Answer (score 15):

You can set both image size and compression level of the exported file by doing something like

```
Export[file_name, G, ImageSize -> 1200, "CompressionLevel" -> 0]
```

Comment: The `"CompressionLevel"` options is mainly for lossy formats as JPG, it produces huge files. Much better is to use lossless formats as PNG for illustrations with plain colors and sharp edges: the file is much smaller, the quality is perfect. And even better to switch to a vector format: PDF or EPS.

Answer (score 12):

The best way I find is to use ImageResolution property. It Increases the resolution of exported image but does not change the scale. Use it like this:

```
Export[ "image-file-name.png", image, ImageResolution -> 500 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of your graph before exporting it:
Graph[theGraph, ImageSize->2000]